# Convert asp.net / MS proprietary json Dateformat to java8 LocalDateTime with jackson while deserializing json to object

Tags: datetime, spring-boot, java-8, jackson, deserialization

I call a webservice from a Spring Boot App, using jackson-jsr-310 as maven dependency for being able to make use of `LocalDateTime`:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = this.createHeaders();
ResponseEntity<String> response;
response  = restTemplate.exchange(uri,HttpMethod.GET,new HttpEntity<Object>(httpHeaders),String.class);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
BusinessPartner test = mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), BusinessPartner.class);
```

My problem is in the last line, the code produces this error:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '/Date(591321600000)/' could not be parsed at index 0

The resulting JSON in `response.getBody()` looks like this:

```
{  
    "d":{  
        ...
        "Address":{...},
        "FirstName":"asd",
        "LastName":"asd",
        "BirthDate":"\/Date(591321600000)\/",
    }
}
```

And in my model class, I have the following member:

```
@JsonProperty("BirthDate")
private LocalDateTime birthDate;
```

So, after a bit of searching here I found out that this `/Date(...)/` seems to be a Microsoft-proprietary Dateformat, which Jackson cannot deserialize into an object  per default.

Some questions advise to create a custom `SimpleDateFormat` and apply it to the opbject mapper, which I tried to do, but then I think I miss the right syntax for     `mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("..."));`

I tried with e.g. `mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("/Date(S)/"));`

or at the end even `mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("SSSSSSSSSSSS)"));`

but it seems this does not work, too, so I am out of ideas for now and  hope some people here could help me out.

**edit 1:**

further investigated, it seems one way to go is to write a custom `DateDeSerializer` for jackson. So I tried this:

```
@Component
public class JsonDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

private DateTimeFormatter formatter;

private JsonDateTimeDeserializer() {
    this(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
}

public JsonDateTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
    this.formatter = formatter;
}

@Override
public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException
{
    if (parser.hasTokenId(JsonTokenId.ID_STRING)) {
        String unixEpochString = parser.getText().trim();
        unixEpochString = unixEpochString.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");

        long unixTime = Long.valueOf(unixEpochString);
        if (unixEpochString.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(unixTime), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        localDateTime.format(formatter);

        return localDateTime;
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

which actually returns nearly what I want, annotating my fields in the model using

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDateTimeDeserializer.class)
```

but not exactly: 
This code returns a `LocalDateTime` of value: `1988-09-27T01:00`. 
But in the thirdparty system, the xmlvalue is `1988-09-27T00:00:00`.

As it is obvious, the ZoneId here:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(unixTime), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

is the Problem, apart from a wrong dateformat.

So could someone here please help me out in how to switch to always use zeros for the `time`-part and to get my dateformat right? Would be great!

Comment: `591321600000` is the epoch milli (milliseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z)?

Comment: @Hugo yes, it is. Please see my edit for more info.

Comment: What's the output of `System.out.println(ZoneId.systemDefault())` ?

Comment: it's Europe/Berlin (rainy here) with an offset of +01:00, which is why I said it is obvious what the problem is. Not thought about people from Sao Paolo ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that the number `591321600000` is the epoch milli (number of milliseconds from `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`).

If that's the case, I think that `SimpleDateFormat` can't help you (at least I couldn't find a way to parse a date from the epoch milli using this class). The pattern `S` (according to [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)) is used to format or parse the milliseconds field of a time (so its maximum value is 999) and won't work for your case.

The only way I could make it work is creating a custom deserializer.

First, I created this class:

```
public class SimpleDateTest {

    @JsonProperty("BirthDate")
    private LocalDateTime birthDate;

    // getter and setter
}
```

Then I created the custom deserializer and added it to a custom module:

```
// I'll explain all the details below
public class CustomDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String s = p.getText(); // s is "/Date(591321600000)/"

        // assuming the format is always /Date(number)/
        long millis = Long.parseLong(s.replaceAll("\\/Date\\((\\d+)\\)\\/", "$1"));

        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis); // 1988-09-27T00:00:00Z

        // instant is in UTC (no timezone assigned to it)
        // to get the local datetime, you must provide a timezone
        // I'm just using system's default, but you must use whatever timezone your system uses
        return instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
    }
}

public class CustomDateModule extends SimpleModule {

    public CustomDateModule() {
        addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new CustomDateDeserializer());
    }
}
```

Then I added this module to my mapper and it worked:

```
// using reduced JSON with only the relevant field
String json = "{ \"BirthDate\": \"\\/Date(591321600000)\\/\" }";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
// add my custom module
mapper.registerModule(new CustomDateModule());

SimpleDateTest value = mapper.readValue(json, SimpleDateTest.class);
System.out.println(value.getBirthDate()); // 1988-09-26T21:00
```

---

Now some comments about the deserializer method.

First I converted the millis `591321600000` to an `Instant` (a class that represents a UTC instant). `591321600000` in millis is equivalent to `1988-09-27T00:00:00Z`.

But that's the UTC date/time. To get the **local** date and time, you must know in what timezone you are, because in every timezone it's a different date and time (everybody in the world are at the same instant, but their local date/time might be different, depending on where they are).

In my example, I just used `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, which gets the default timezone of my system. But if you don't want to depend on the default and want to use a specific timezone, use the `ZoneId.of("timezone name")` method (you can get the list of all available timezones names with `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()` - this method returns all valid names accepted by the `ZoneId.of()` method).

As my default timezone is `America/Sao_Paulo`, this code sets the `birthDate` to  `1988-09-26T21:00`.

If you don't want to convert to a specific timezone, you can use the `ZoneOffset.UTC`. So, in the deserializer method, the last line will be:

```
   return instant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
```

Now the local date will be `1988-09-27T00:00` - as we're using UTC offset, there's no timezone conversion and the local date/time is not changed.

---

**PS:** if you need to convert the `birthDate` back to MS's custom format, you can write a custom serializer and add to the custom module as well. To convert a `LocalDateTime` to that format, you can do:

```
LocalDateTime birthDate = value.getBirthDate();
// you must know in what zone you are to convert it to epoch milli (using default as an example)
Instant instant = birthDate.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
String msFormat = "/Date(" + instant.toEpochMilli() + ")/";
System.out.println(msFormat); // /Date(591321600000)/
```

Note that, to convert a `LocalDateTime` to `Instant`, you must know in what timezone you are. In this case, I recommend to use the same timezone for serializing and deserializing (in your case, you can use `ZoneOffset.UTC` instead of `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.

Comment: actually, this is pretty close to where I got :) I'll accept your answer for this actually solves 95%. Would be great if you could help me with my last problems in my edit, though!

Comment: The hour shift happens because you're convertin the UTC value (Instant) to your timezone.

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to NOT do that? As far as I see it, one has to provide a timezone.

Comment: Yes, it is, see my edit: just use `ZoneOffset.UTC` instead of `ZoneId.systemDefault()`

Comment: Thanks a lot....My only problem is that I received Date(1443630600000+0200) adn I have to send in the same format. It'is possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some Groovy code I wrote that also handles the timezone offset: https://gist.github.com/jeffsheets/938733963c03208afd74927fb6130884

```
class JsonDotNetLocalDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt) {
        convertDotNetDateToJava(parser.text.trim())
    }

    /**
     * Returns a Java LocalDateTime when given a .Net Date String
     * /Date(1535491858840-0500)/
     */
    static LocalDateTime convertDotNetDateToJava(String dotNetDate) {
        // Strip the prefix and suffix to just 1535491858840-0500
        String epochAndOffset = dotNetDate[6..-3]

        // 1535491858840
        String epoch = epochAndOffset[0..-6]

        // -0500 Note, keep the negative/positive indicator
        String offset = epochAndOffset[-5..-1]
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("UTC${offset}")

        LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(epoch.toLong()), zoneId)
    }
}
```